# Lucene 3.0.2 features

Tags: java, lucene

What are new features in lucene 3.0.2?

Comment: [Lucene Change Log](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/changes/Changes.html#3.0.2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here they are, in the [changelog](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/changes/Changes.html#3.0.2)