# Diff in Lucene 2.2 and 3.0.2

Tags: lucene

Feature wise Difference in Lucene 2.2 and Lucene 3.0.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lucene 3.0.2 features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345862/lucene-3-0-2-features)

Comment: Why not read the release notes?

Answer (score 4):

All the changes for each release are listed in the release note.  Read them.

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/changes/Changes.html